# boost log - undefined reference when using a global logger

Tags: c++, boost

I have successfully built a boost example **rotating_file** (boost 1.63) using my own cmake file instead of jamfile. Then I have add following modification:

```
#include <boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp>
...
//before main
BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER(my_logger, src::logger)
...
//src::logger lg;
src::logger& lg = my_logger::get();
```

A program also contains this line:

```
#define BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK
```

Here are cmake libs:

```
target_link_libraries(test "libboost_log.so"
                           "libboost_log_setup.so"
                           "libboost_date_time.so"
                           "libboost_filesystem.so"
                           "libboost_system.so"
                           "libboost_thread.so")
```

This line:

```
src::logger& lg = my_logger::get();
```

generates:

```
global_logger_storage.hpp:154: error: undefined reference to `my_logger::construct_logger()'
```

What is wrong ?

**Edit**

I add sink and other attributes this way:

```
logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("TimeStamp", attrs::local_clock());
logging::core::get()->add_global_attribute("RecordID", attrs::counter< unsigned int >());
```

so at the end of the BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT I just add:

```
src::logger logger;
return logger;
```

It works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a call to [BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/log/doc/html/BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT.html). In one project I have the following in a header:

```
// register a global logger
BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER(logger, boost::log::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::trivial::severity_level>)
```

In the source file I have this:

```
BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT(logger, src::severity_logger_mt) {
    src::severity_logger_mt<boost::log::trivial::severity_level> logger;

    // add attributes
    logger.add_attribute("LineID", attrs::counter<unsigned int>(1));    // lines are sequentially numbered
    logger.add_attribute("TimeStamp", attrs::local_clock());             // each log line gets a timestamp

    return logger;
}
```

When I comment out the BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT, I get the same error as you do. My powers of deduction tell me that BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_INIT provides the definition that you (we) need.

Comment: Works, please see Edit

Comment: As you can see in the docs (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/sources.html#log.detailed.sources.global_storage), there are a few other macros to define the logger initialization. Judging by the edit, you could use ` BOOST_LOG_GLOBAL_LOGGER_DEFAULT`.